# what does "the difference between Jay-Z and Jay-Y" mean?

Tags: yesterday-2019

In musical fantasy movie *Yesterday* (2019), Jack says to Ellie:

> Jack: I know the songs are strong, but no one's interested still. Jack
>   Malik's the problem. It is. I just don't have the "it" that's the
>   **difference between Jay-Z and Jay-Y**.

Comment: Lol. I Haven't seen this, but it sounds like the speaker is making a point using a made up "Jay-Y" moniker. See, the very existence of "Jay-Z" denotes the existence of Jays A through Y (all of which can be assumed failures). So "Jay-Z" is the final, complete product.

Comment: Mark Twain said: "The difference between the almost right word and the right word is really a large matter. ’tis the difference between the lightning bug and the lightning."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a reference to the hugely famous [rap artist Jay-Z](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay-Z).  The point is that there may seem to be no *a priori* distinction between a song by an artist named "Jay-Y" and one by Jay-Z. However, in reality, if there is Jay-Y, nobody has heard of them, while Jay-Z has been tremendously innovative and popular.

In a nutshell:  You may not be able to see the difference, but one is forgettable nothing, while the other is the real deal, the material listeners actually want.

Comment: It's kind of like Mark Twain pointing out the difference between "lightning" and "lightning bug"

Comment: As was noted, @user888379, [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232285/what-does-the-difference-between-jay-z-and-jay-y-mean#comment636205_232285) about 2 years ago. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan Oops - noticed the June part, but not the 2020 part.